# GRID ERROR in raster calculator of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I wrote and ran this formula in raster calculator in ARCGIS. But the following error gets me into trouble.

Does anyone have a suggestion to overcome this?

Here is the formula I wrote and the error that appears.

What is wrong with this formula?

[image: error while working in raster calculator]

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS? The Raster Calculator appears to change with every update. In ArcGIS 9.3, for instance, this problem was reported and solved at http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=995&t=271919.

Comment: give spaces between the `(` and `[`, e.g. `( Float ( [temp_2009_all.tif] )` instead of `(Float([temp_2009_all.tif])`